# Show marker on Google Maps Javascript external link

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On the Google Maps javascript, there is a clickable link at the bottom left of the map with the Google icon to "See this area on Google Maps". This link opens up Google Maps, however, it only centers on the latitude/longitude provided and doesn't show the marker I provide to the API.

```
                    function initMap() {
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_holder'), {
                        center: {lat: 37.423021, lng: -122.083739},
                        zoom: 15
                    });

                    map.setOptions({draggable: false, zoomControl: true, scrollwheel: false, disableDoubleClickZoom: true});


                    var coord = new google.maps.LatLng(37.423021, -122.083739);

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: coord,
                        map: map
                      });

                }
```

I know there is a way to produce an URL that will show a marker, such an example would be http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:36.26577,-92.54324, but I can't seem to figure out from the API.

Answer (score -1):

Should be:

```
function initMap() {
  var center = {lat: 37.423021, lng: -122.083739};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_holder'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: center
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: center,
    map: map
  });

  // you can set other options
}
```

More info:

1. You can find required properties here: [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions)
2. Example: [Simple markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=en)

**EDIT:**
@Sefam, I edited your code because I saw some difference with example. I edited my answer to show where is the difference.

```
function initMap() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_holder'), {
      center: {lat: 37.423021, lng: -122.083739}, // or try:
      // center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat: 37.423021, lng: -122.083739),
      zoom: 15
   });

   map.setOptions({draggable: false, zoomControl: true, scrollwheel: false, disableDoubleClickZoom: true}); 

   var coord = new google.maps.LatLng(37.423021, -122.083739); // here you created instance of LatLng's class

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coord, // instead this try:
      //position: {lat: 37.423021, lng: -122.083739}, // here is a difference;  or try:
      //position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat: 37.423021, lng: -122.083739),
      map: map
   });
}
```

If it doesn't work check your api key and callback function:

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Also check css rules: did you set `height` for your map?

Also I want to explain why I gave two variants of creating properties `center` and `position`:

```
center: {lat: 37.423021, lng: -122.083739}
center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat: 37.423021, lng: -122.083739)

position: {lat: 37.423021, lng: -122.083739}
position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat: 37.423021, lng: -122.083739)
```

In my practice I used both variants and both works.

Try combinations:

```
center: {lat: 37.423021, lng: -122.083739} //for var map
position: {lat: 37.423021, lng: -122.083739} //for var marker

center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat: 37.423021, lng: -122.083739) //for var map
position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat: 37.423021, lng: -122.083739) //for var marker
```

Hope my edited answer help you to find solution. **Please, post error message from console if my answer doesn't help**. With error message more easier to find solution.

PS. When I need to create Google Map I always use Google Maps APIs examples and it always works.

Comment: I don't see how this is any different from my code other than declaring the coord variable earlier and using it for the center option in the options array in map's initialization. Your "Simple Markers" example has the same problem I do, if you click on the Google icon at the bottom left of the map, it refers to Google Maps, centers the map on the marker location, but doesn't show a marker. The fact that it doesn't do that is my issue in this case.

Comment: @Sefam, please look to your code. Problem with var coord. For var marker try: position: {lat: 37.423021, lng: -122.083739} or postion: center (if use my code)